# Empty dataset indicator for RecyclerView not showing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-search

I'm trying to show a Snackbar with a message whenever the dataset of a filtered RecyclerView contains 0 items but for some reason, the Snackbar doesn't appear at all. Does the relevant code need to go in the Fragment or Adapter? Can this be donw without libraries?

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private var mAdapter: MyAdapter? = null
    private lateinit var mSearchView: SearchView
    private lateinit var mSearchMenuItem: MenuItem
    private val myList = ArrayList<Item>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false)

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView)
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager =
            androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager(this.activity)
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration(
                        context, LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                )
        )

        myList.add(
                Item(
                        getString(R.string.item_a)
                )
        )

        mAdapter = MyAdapter(requireActivity(), myList)

        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
         val mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(
                requireView(),
                getString(R.string.no_items),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
        )
        
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                mAdapter!!.filter.filter(newText)
                mAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                if (mAdapter!!.itemCount <1) {
                    mSnackbar.show()
                } else {
                    mSnackbar.dismiss()
                }

                return false
            }
        })

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
}
```

**Adapter code**

```
class MyAdapter(
    private val mCtx: Context,
    var myList: MutableList<Item>,
) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    private val myListFull = myList.toMutableList()

val mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(
        requireView(),
        getString(R.string.my_message),
        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
)

    private val companyFilter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filteredList = ArrayList<Item>()

            if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                filteredList.addAll(myListFull)
            } else {
                val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim { it <= ' ' }

                for (item in myListFull) {
                    if (item.Name.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)
                    ) {
                        filteredList.add(item)
                    }
                }
            }

            val results = FilterResults()
            results.values = filteredList
            return results
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            myList.clear()
            myList.addAll(results!!.values as List<Item>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()

        if (filteredList.isEmpty()) {
            mSnackbar.show()
        } else {
            mSnackbar.dismiss()
        }

        }
    }

    private fun String.matchesIgnoreCase(otherString: String): Boolean {
        return this.toLowerCase().contains(otherString.trim().toLowerCase())
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    .ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
        var tvSubtitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return companyFilter
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your filter codes in adapter.

Comment: @sadat Added. Forgot to indent the code.

Comment: I think you should keep a separate instance for val filteredList = ArrayList<Item>() and return filteredList.count from getcount function.

Comment: Do you mean to replace `myList.size` with `filteredList.count` in the `getItemCount` function?

Comment: yes. otherwise if you update mList, you will basically lose the data anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter):

> Filtering operations performed by calling `filter(java.lang.CharSequence)` or `filter(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.Filter.FilterListener)` **are performed asynchronously**. When these methods are called, a filtering request is **posted in a request queue and processed later**.

So you're checking `myList` (through `getItemCount`) immediately after calling `filter`, and the data hasn't updated yet because the filter / publish stuff hasn't finished running. So your snackbar gets dismissed

The `publishResults` method runs on the UI thread, so maybe display the snackbar there, if you need to?

Comment: This will not work because the list will appear blank when the fragment is loaded. Please post your suggested code.

Comment: If this is the problem (which is probably is since the filtering is async) then you'll have to show/dismiss your snackbar after your ``publishResults`` code runs. It's up to you how you do that! I'm just helping you find where the problem is

Comment: `requireView()` doesn't work in an adapter so what should I be using instead? I also noticed that `getString()` doesn't work either.

Comment: ``requireView()`` is a method on a ``Fragment`` (or ``Activity``) that gets its layout view (or throws an exception if it can't access it, like if it's not added yet). It's the one you're creating in ``onCreateView``. ``getString()`` is also a ``Fragment`` method but you can run it on a ``Context`` as well. It might be best to pass those things into your adapter when you create it, or some kind of callback listener so the ``Fragment`` can handle displaying the snackbar, so that's separate from the adapter. ``Fragment``s don't always have a context or activity though...

Comment: I'd strongly prefer to use the option with less code as possible. I have added `mCtx.getResources` before `getString` and that that part now works. Can something like this be used for the `view` part?

Comment: Just pass the view you inflated into the adapter's constructor, that's probably easiest? And the reason I suggested moving the snackbar stuff out of the adapter is because really, you should be doing more checking to see if you have a ``Context``/``Activity`` yet, ``requireActivity`` will crash if the fragment isn't associated with one yet, which can happen with things like fragment recreation. Just giving you a heads up!